# Bootstrap Problemas con el sidebar en angular o css

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap

estoy actualmente iniciando con Angular y Firebase.

Hoy tengo un detalle el cual no sé de que manera resolverlo y no se precisamente donde debería buscar la solución. Uso el template SB 2 Admin que [aquí se ofrece](https://startbootstrap.com/themes/sb-admin-2/) y funciona bastante bien. Al momento de separar por componentes, como el header, sidebar y footer me encontré con un detalle que me gustaría resolver antes de continuar.

En código tengo dividido de la siguiente manera:

```
 <div id="wrapper">
    <app-sidebar></app-sidebar>
</div>
```

y obviamente todo el sidebar en el app-sidebar, se ajusta a la pantalla pero cuando hay mas, no se termina de llenar. Adjunto como se ve:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si notan que no si bien se ve bien, cuando desplazo para abajo se nota que no se termino de pintar. Cuando no lo pongo en componente, es decir todo el codigo funciona de maravilla, pero creo que no es el caso.
Asi lo pongo para que funcione:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <ul class="navbar-nav  sidebar accordion">
...
  </ul>
</div>
```

Cuando funciona se ve así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No sé si tengo que editar algo en bootstrap, no creo que alguien mas en sus primeros pasos no le haya pasado y tampoco se si es mas de bootstrap o css o angular.

Nota: Uso Bs 4.4, Angular 9

Comment: Añade el código que has intentado hasta ahora para que algún compañero pueda ayudarte de la mejor manera posible.

Answer (score 0):

Así empieza mi sidebar uso la misma plantilla
Es me ocurrió hace unos meses lo pude resolver con la propiedad heigh, agradecería tú puntuación si te sirve.

```
<ul class="navbar-nav bg-gradient-primary sidebar sidebar-dark accordion" id="accordionSidebar"> 
.navbar-nav { 
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
padding-left: 0;
margin-bottom: 0;
list-style: none;`
height: calc(100% ) !important;
}
```